# Facebook API For Wall Post

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to post on facebook wall through `FB API` and getting this Error in console.

```
error   
Object { message="(#200) The user hasn't a... to perform this action", type="OAuthException", code=200} 
code    200 
message

    "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"  
type :"OAuthException"
```

**I am trying this way.**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    // replacing with an older version until FB fixes the cancel-login bug
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    //e.src = 'scripts/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init({
        appId  : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true , // parse XFBML
        oauth : true // Enable oauth authentication
    });




};


function post_on_wall()
{
    FB.login(function(response)
    {
        if (response.authResponse)
        {
            alert('Logged in!');

            // Post message to your wall

            var opts = {
                message : document.getElementById('fb_message').value,
                name : 'Post Title',
                link : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                description : 'post description Nanital',
                picture : 'ImageLink'
            };

            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', opts, function(response)
            {

                if (!response || response.error)
                {
                    alert('Posting error occured');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Success - Post ID: ' + response.id);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Not logged in');
        }
    }, { scope : 'publish_stream' });
}


</script>
```

**Note: It is working fine, If i loggedin with same id which through i create this APP. But not working for other facebook user.**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `publish_stream` is deprecated since years. You need `publish_actions`:

> A user access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new posts

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed

**That being said, you need to go through a review process with `publish_actions` before you can use it for every other user: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login**

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I have already try all these scope(  `publish_stream,user_photos,friends_photos,email,share_item,status_update,read_stream`) one by one and combined too. but error is still persist same.

Comment: why do you try all those permissions? you should only use them if you NEED them, it´s all explained when you need them in the docs...

Comment: anyway, for posting on your own wall, you ONLY need publish_actions, i have added a link to the docs. but you really need to read the last paragraph of my answer. that´s exactly what your problem is. i have made it bold.